# Is there a way - in ASP.Net - to access one ObjectDataSource's object from another ObjectDataSource in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have following code in aspx page:

```xml
<asp:ObjectDataSource id="odsOuterSource" TypeName="my.namespace.page"
SelectMethod="GetTestObject" DataObjectTypeName="my.namespace.Entities.TestObject" />

<asp:ObjectDataSource id="odsInnerSource" TypeName="my.namespace.page"
SelectMethod="GetAnotherTestObject" 
DataObjectTypeName="my.namespace.Entities.AnotherTestObject" />
```

and following code in code-behind:

```cs
public TestObject GetTestObject()
{
    Logic myLogic = new MyLogic();
    return myLogic.GetTestObject();
}

public AnotherTestObject GetAnotherTestObject()
{
    Logic myLogic = new MyLogic();
    return myLogic.GetAnotherTestObject(testObject);
}
```

Now my question is if there is a way to get the TestObject which was returned by the OuterSource so that I could use it for the InnerSource without having to call GetTestObject again.

I hope you can help me with this.

Edit: For better readability than a comment

Thanks for your answers, but i have a question to Mudu's answer:

Is there a way to do this if my OuterSource has a parameter?
For example

```xml
<asp:ObjectDataSource id="odsOuterSource" TypeName="my.namespace.page"
SelectMethod="GetTestObject" DataObjectTypeName="my.namespace.Entities.TestObject">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" QueryStringField="id" DefaultValue="0" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

because then even my GetTestObject would have a parameter:

```
public TestObject GetTestObject(int id)
{
    Logic myLogic = new MyLogic();
    return myLogic.GetTestObject(id);
}
```

Comment: If you have a need for this kind of complexity, then ObjectDataSource is not the data object you want to use. Consider EF or Linq2Sql.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: don't these have different responsibilities? His problem is the ODS itself, not the way ODS fetches the data.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: The ODS is a limited use "black box" object. My understanding of the question suggests that he is attempting to use this object outside of that black box. To me that indicates he's using the wrong object. I may be wrong, but I think the consideration is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save it in a member, either as `TestObject` or as a `Lazy<TestObject>`:

```
private readonly Lazy<TestObject> myTestObject = new Lazy<TestObject>(() =>
{
    var myLogic = new MyLogic();
    return myLogic.GetTestObject();
});
```

With this code, you can receive it any number of times you want. It will be fetched via `MyLogic` once and re-returned on subsequent invocations:

```
public TestObject GetTestObject()
{
    return this.myTestObject.Value;
}

public AnotherTestObject GetAnotherTestObject()
{
    var testObject = this.myTestObject.Value; // re-used

    Logic myLogic = new MyLogic();
    return myLogic.GetAnotherTestObject(testObject);
}
```

As ASP.NET creates a new instance of your page for each request, the `Lazy<TestObject>` object is recreated for each request. Therefore, your `TestObject` is actually fetched once per request.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Is there a way to do this if my OuterSource has a parameter?
For Example:
<asp:ObjectDataSource id="odsOuterSource" TypeName="my.namespace.page"
SelectMethod="GetTestObject" DataObjectTypeName="my.namespace.Entities.TestObject">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id"
    QueryStringField="id" DefaultValue="0" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

Comment: @TimvdBerg Well, given the parameter has *the same value all queries within the same request*, you can also initialize your `Lazy<TestObject>` in the data source's `Selecting` handler. However, I'd rather check whether you can access the parameter directly in code (like `Request.QueryString["id"]` in the `Lazy<TestObject>`'s object creation function).